# jQuery Linking to a Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make it so I can link to specific tabs but can't seem to get it to work properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

HTML

```
<div class="tab-ct">

    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
        <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
         Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </div>
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
        Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>

</div>
```

JS

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $('.tab-link').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab'), $ct = $(this).closest('.tab-ct');

     $ct.find('ul.tabs li.current').removeClass('current');
     $ct.find('.tab-content.current').removeClass('current');

    $("li.tab-link[data-tab='"+ tab_id+"']").addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
  });

});
```

Comment: I tried to run your code and everything seems working fine.... what does "can't seem to get it to work properly" mean? Plese, be more specific...

Comment: Sorry, hopefully this clears it up. Lets say I have a tab with the id "settings", I want to link to this tab from another page. Normally I would use <a href="index.html#settings">settings</a> but with tabs it doesn't seem to work. It will take me to the page but the tab with the "settings" id is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... reading your explanation of the problem, I see there is one thing you are missing.

How anchors work: they just move the browser window to a point of the page. It is a standard behaviour and it is independent from the attributes (and the content) of your div.

Your tabbed browsing is not a standard component, but it has several custom behaviours you wrote by JS.
So you should say to your JS code (on page loading) to intercept the name of the anchor, then to add "current" classe to the proper element.

I can't know details of the navigation you are implementing (and it is possible you need to modify a bit your code), but you need something like:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

     var hash = window.location.hash; // to get content after # in the URL
 if (hash.indexOf("tab-") === 0) {
     $("#"+hash).siblings('div').each(function() { 
         $(this).removeClass('current');
     });
     $("#"+hash).siblings('ul').children("li").each(function() { 
         $(this).removeClass('current');
     });
     var tab_id = $("#"+hash).addClass('current');
    $("li.tab-link[data-tab='"+ hash+"']").addClass('current');         
 }


  $('.tab-link').click(function(){
    // your existing code
  });

});
```

Hope it helps

UPDATE: I add a basic implementation able to work also if different groups of tabs are present in the page

Comment: I appreciate the help, I'm still learning and got the code for the tabs from another site. For the navigation part, the tabs are called like in the example I gave. I'm not sure exactly what to put in the code to manage part though but I'll look into hash and see if I can get this to work.

Comment: In my mind try to well understand what your code (the code you copied) does: it will help you to learn in a shortest time... ;) By the way see my updated reply (and, please, mark it as "solution" if you appreciate)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll give it a try.